# AUTOHOTKEY - How can I get a hotstring to initiate without a preceding space?

Tags: autohotkey

I've got a hotkey definition:

```
:*:()::(){left}
```

If I write something like this:

```
word ()
```

The cursor ends up between the parentheses.  :)  But if I write something like this:

```
function()
```

The cursor ends up to the right of the parentheses.  How can I change my hotstring to always put my cursor between the parentheses, regardless of a preceding space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:?*:()::(){left}
```

**? (question mark)**: The hotstring will be triggered even when it is inside another word. Use **?0** to turn this option back off.

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options

Comment: Thanks so much!  I just tested this(it works!!)  Thanks again!